# No me funciona la funcion nl2br() de PHP para un textarea en un form

Tags: php, html, funcion

como estan?
Hice un formulario en el cual hay un textarea. Mi idea es hacer que todo lo que escriba ahi, cada vez que doy un enter, el texto baje, y esto mismo se refleje despues en pantalla. El problema es que lo uso, parece funcionar porque genera los `<br>`, pero en pantalla se imprimen tambien los `<br>` sin hacer los saltos de linea.

MUESTRO PRIMERO LA SECCION DEL FORMULARIO:

```
    <div class="form-fila">
        <label for="caracteristicas" class="invisible">Caracteristicas</label>
        <textarea
            id="caracteristicas"
            name="caracteristicas"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Caracteristicas"
            <?php if(isset($errores['caracteristicas'])): ?> aria-describedby="error-caracteristicas" <?php endif; ?>
        ><?= e($dataForm['caracteristicas'] ?? null);?></textarea>
        <?php
        if(isset($errores['caracteristicas'])):
        ?>
            <div class="msg-error" id="error-caracteristicas"><span class="visually-hidden">Error: </span><?= $errores['caracteristicas'];?></div>
        <?php
        endif;
        ?>
    </div>
```

MUESTRO ACA DONDE APLICO LA FUNCION (ESTO EN EL ARCHIVO DONDE ENVIA EL FORM):

```
$caracteristicas    = nl2br($_POST['caracteristicas'], false);
```

COMO SE VE EN PANTALLA:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

TAMBIEN USO UNA FUNCION PARA PROTEGER DE CIERTOS CARACTERES, PERO NO SE SI SEA ESO, Y EN TODO CASO COMO PUEDO HACER UNA EXCEPCION PARA LOS BR?:

```
<?php
/**
 * Transforma un string a una versión slugificada amigable para URLs.
 *
 * @param string $string
 * @return string
 */
function slugify(string $string): string
{
    $search = [' ', '%', '+', '\'', '"', '`', '´'];
    $replace = ['-', '', '-', '', '', '', ''];
    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
}

/**
 * Wrapper de htmlspecialchars.
 *
 * @param null|string $string
 * @return string
 */
function e(?string $string): string
{
    return htmlspecialchars($string);
}
```

Les agradeceria mucho si me dan una mano, es importante que las caracteristicas se vean una debajo de la otra.

Comment: El textarea por defecto no acepta HTML. Así que entiende los `\n`, no hace falta que intentes poner código HTML dentro.

Comment: Pero una vez que imprimís en pantalla el contenido con los <br>, no tendría que  reconocer las etiquetas?

Comment: Dentro de un textarea no, solo muestra texto sin formato, asi que si escribes etiquetas en el se veran tal cual sin ser interpretadas por el navegador.  Míralo en su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

Comment: Si lo que quieres es mostrar HTML usa cualquier otro elemento, como un DIV.  Los textarea son para editar campos, no para mostrarlos con formato.

Comment: Pero la idea es que es un panel de administracion. Por eso uso el formulario, para ir llenando con inputs el titulo, precio, imagen, y con un textarea queria que sea para las caracteristicas. Esta data tambien va a una base de datos MySQL. La imagen que hay ahi es la pantalla de del panel de administracion, que toma los datos de la base de datos. Al ser un formulario si o si debo usar un textarea. Me basé en este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iepE1yLIkBE

Comment: En el formulario usa el textarea, claro, pero cuando los muestres **no**, y es entonces que puedes usar la función nl2br(), **pero no dentro del textarea** que es solo para la edición, no para mostrarlos después (si te fijas bien en el video, cuando los muestran con el nl2br **no estan dentro del textarea**, sino que hace un print a secas sin ese elemento.

Comment: me debo explicar fatal si aun no lo has entendido, lo siento

Comment: No, el que entiende fatal soy yo ajaja. Ahi lo resolví. Claro era una boludez. Ponerle la funcion al div de una. Mil gracias!!